# Celling fan work only when separate light switch is on

Tags: ceiling-fan, dimmer-switch

I replaced one of the light switches with a dimmer now ceiling fan only works when the light switch is switched on.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the switch box please?

Comment: Did you make a record of how the lod light switch was wired before you replaced it?